# Google Chrome extension that enables a specific website to trigger a function in the extension code

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I'm new to extension development, maybe someone has a small example ready for my problem.
I plan a more complicate code (that will execute chromium API functions), but solving this task should help me get started:

I want to create an extension that triggers a popup or alert() (just anyything) based on a website javascript call.

So for example my website has a button, when clicked on the button a javascript with a few parameters is executed.
My extension picks those parameters up and executes APIs (for my example just any popup) based on the parameters.
In my basic example I'd like to trigger some sort of popup/notification with the text supplied by the website javascript.
Also only my website domain should be allowed to trigger that, anything else should be rejected.

I'd really appreciate help.
Here is my "empty" manifest

```
{
    "name": "Special API",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "API demo extension.",
  "browser_action": 
  {
    "default_icon": "gears.ico",
    "popup": "show_credits.htm"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://www.mywebsite.com/"
  ]
}
```

Here the example button in my website.com/example

```
<html>
<body>
<button onClick="extension_do_exec('Hellow world','abcabc')">Execute extension function</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you described is problematic, bacause javascripts of web-pages, and javascripts of extensions are isolated from each other (there is a concept of [isolated world](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment)). So it is not possible to get a value "supplied by the website javascript" directly into the extension's javascript. I'd suggest another approach. You possibly could exchange with some values by assigning them as properties to DOM objects. These properties can be accessed from a content script, injected into the web-page. Of course, the content script can determine domain of the page and work as appropriate. As for popups, these are internal pages of an extension, and you should implement some kind of [messaging](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) between them and your content script.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed solved it that way.
I use a contentscript, a hidden div and a customevent like it is described on your documentation link for messaging.